# Windows phone map broken multitasking

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7, dictionary

When user opens map, my app starts loading much data from DB to show on map (when it's loaded).
But what i see is that map control stops loading/showing tiles when BG thread is loaded with hard work.

AFAIK WP7 doesn't support thread priorities.

This is really weird. Simple `while(true)` on BG thread stops map from showing new geodata on zoom/pan.

Maybe any ideas ?

Repro project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/21fmgepcdzf3u1n/Map_bug_Repro.zip

If you start it - map won't load. If you edit `MainPage.xaml.cs` and comment thread creation - it will work fine.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you creating your background thread?

Comment: KooKiz - tried in many different ways(TPool, new Thread, RX, Tasks, whatever). This doesn't matter. 
Matt - added URL to repro to initial msg.